# Passing an error testing suite in contract

Tags: javascript, testing, truffle-test, test, chai

hello how do i make a proper testing suite for error?

the contract has this modifier for freeMint() fn

```
    modifier protectTier(uint256 _level) {
        require(
            _level != privateTier, "Exclusive tier"
        );
        _;
    }
```

and my testing script

```js
  it("Should failed minting tier 1 with freeMint func", async () => {
    let txn = await genesisNFT.freeMint(12, 1);
    await expect(txn.wait()).to.be.revertedWith("Exclusive tier");
  });
```

and error test still failing like this

```
   Should failed minting tier 1 with freeMint func:
     Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: reverted with reason string 'Exclusive tier'
```

Answer (score 0):

As I know `tx.wait()` is used for waiting transaction is confirmed by other nodes.You can't test revert event by passing `tx.wait()` to `expect()` beacause `tx` is reverted by evm when you send it by this line:

```
let txn = await genesisNFT.freeMint(12, 1);
```

So your assserting line should be like this:

```
await expect(genesisNFT.freeMint(12, 1)).to.be.revertedWith("Exclusive tier");
```